# TinyMCE - Ben Long article from Aug2020 no longer accurate for Inline - how should it be done now?

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm trying to move to inline for TinyMCE and came across this article from a year ago, by Ben Long, on "Blueprint by Tiny".  It breaks/doesn't work, when you get to applying the QuickBars.  They just don't appear.

Can anyone tell me why not and where I should be placing the QuickBar code?

[An inline editor for any application](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/inline-editor)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script>
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#mydiv",
  inline: true,
  quickbars_selection_toolbar:
    "styleselect | bold italic forecolor | removeformat",
  quickbars_insert_toolbar: false,
  menubar: false,
  toolbar: false,
});
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mydiv" style="margin: 50px">
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      <p>Are you interested in a pair of...</p>
    <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you see `You will be presented with a warning notification - This domain is not registered with Tiny Cloud - if you are running TinyMCE on your local machine outside of a web server, or if the domain on which you’re running TinyMCE is not registered against your account. To remove the notification, open it on localhost (which is already an approved domain by default), or register your domain as an approved domain in your account.`

Answer (score 0):

OK...  found the answer, so just in case it should be of use to anyone else:

The QuickBar plugin has to be activated as well.  So that's what's missing.

```html
tinymce.init({
  selector: "#mydiv",
  inline: true,
  plugins: [ 'quickbars' ],
  quickbars_selection_toolbar:
    "styleselect | bold italic forecolor | removeformat",
  quickbars_insert_toolbar: false,
  menubar: false,
  toolbar: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for testing this out, and fixing a gap in the code sample. I've updated the blog to match the code sample:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thanks RobinJoe.   

I wonder if you could perhaps give me some help with another aspect of TinyMCE, when using inline...

I really want to get rid of the Blue Line / box around the Tiny element.  I've searched the web for a long time, without luck.  I posted a question here, but no replies so far:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69377473/how-to-remove-the-blue-line-around-the-tinymce-5-editor-inline-mode