# How to remove the Blue Line around the TinyMCE-5 editor - inline mode

Tags: inline, inline-styles, tinymce-5

Can anyone help with how to remove the Blue Line around the **TinyMCE 5** Editor?

Specifically, when using the '**inline**' implementation of **Distraction-Free**, which shows when the editor is active.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks RobinJoe.

I found the answer on the Tiny 'inline' CodePen.  This does it:

```
  <style>
  * [contentEditable="true"]:focus
  { outline: 0px ; }
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this might have something to do with the `content_css` configuration option. This option handles the styling of content inside the editor, which might include the blue border. We have a blog post about customising the styling - https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-css-and-custom-styles/